# Memory resources for a docker container running from docker-compose

Tags: docker, memory-management, docker-compose, sonarqube, resources

I’m running Sonarqube on Docker compose and my file looks like this:

```
version: "3"


services:
  sonarqube:
    image: sonarqube
    ports:
     - "9000:9000"
     - "5432:5432"
    links:
      - db:db
    environment:
     - SONARQUBE_JDBC_URL=jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/sonar
     - SONARQUBE_JDBC_USERNAME=postgres
     - SONARQUBE_JDBC_PASSWORD=sonar
    volumes:
     - ..../Work/tools/_SonarQube_home/conf:/opt/sonarqube/conf
#     - sonarqube_data:/opt/sonarqube_new/data
     - ...../Work/tools/_SonarQube_home/data:/opt/sonarqube/data
     - ....../Work/tools/_SonarQube_home/extensions:/opt/sonarqube/extensions
     - ..../Work/tools/_SonarQube_home/bundled-plugins:/opt/sonarqube/lib/bundled-plugins

  db:
    image: postgres
    environment:
     - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
     - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=sonar
     - POSTGRES_DB=sonar
    volumes:
     - .../Work/tools/_PostgreSQL_data:/var/lib/postgresql
     # This needs explicit mapping due to https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/4e48e3228a30763913ece952c611e5e9b95c8759/Dockerfile.template#L52
     - ..../Work/tools/_PostgreSQL_data/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

Everything works and that’s great. One moment I saw that Sonarqube instance started to act slowly, therefore I checked `docker stats`. It looks like this:

```
| CPU   | Mem Usage/ Limit   |
|-------| --------------------
| 5.39% | 1.6GiB / 1.952GiB  |
```

How do I define more RAM resources for the server, let’s say 4 GB? Previously it was `mem_limit` but now on version 3 it doesn’t exist.
What would be a good solution for that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Compose file version 3, resource limits [moved](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-versioning/#version-2x-to-3x) to under a [`deploy: {resources: ...}`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#resources) key, but are also only documented to work in Swarm mode.  So to actually set them you need to switch to a mostly-compatible version 2 Compose file.

```
version: '2'
services:
  sonarqube:
    mem_limit: 4g
```

[The default](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#user-memory-constraints) should be for the container to be able to use an unlimited amount of memory.  If you're running in an environment where Docker is inside a Linux VM (anything based on Docker Toolbox or Docker Machine, Docker for Mac) it's limited by the memory size of the VM.

Comment: Thanks! that seems to be the way.

Answer (score 1):

If you are deploying to Swarm, then you can use the `resources` keyword in your Compose file. (it's described under Resources in the file reference https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/)

So you can do something like this is Swarm:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  redis:
    image: redis:alpine
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: '0.50'
          memory: 50M
        reservations:
          cpus: '0.25'
          memory: 20M
```

If you are using Compose, then you have the option to go back to Compose file version 2.0, as described in the Compose file reference by Docker.

> Looking for options to set resources on non swarm mode containers?
>
> The options described here are specific to the deploy key and swarm mode. If you want to set resource constraints on non swarm
>   deployments, use Compose file format version 2 CPU, memory, and other
>   resource options. If you have further questions, refer to the
>   discussion on the GitHub issue docker/compose/4513.

I'm not familiar with Sonarqube memory issue, but you may want to have a look at this https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONARqube71/Java+Process+Memory.